# SQLite3 selection works on simulator but it does not on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, sqlite, ios-simulator

I am storing a collection of values in a table with several columns of different types, and inserting and selecting works fine when I run the app on the iPhone simulator. However, when running on a real device and selecting the data, it looks like it fails to get some of the text columns of the table (rest of columns seem to be correctly retrieved). Where I should be shown a dialog with a string, I am not, I get an empty dialog, whereas the dialog with the string was properly displayed on the simulator.

This is the code snippet for the insertion:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement,
                          -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, userData.ID);
        sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement, 2, userData.Location.Lat);
        sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement, 3, userData.Location.Lon);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [userData.Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 5, [userData.Surname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }

    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(compiledStatement));
    }
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

And this is the selection:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            UserData *userData = [[UserData alloc] init];

            userData.ID = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);

            char *name = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
            if (name == nil)
                userData.Name = @"";
            else
                userData.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: name];

            [list addObject:userData];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

I have absolutely no idea why database data management is behaving well in simulator (I have SQLite Manager plugin and data is correctly stored and retrieved), but it is not in a real iPhone. How could I check what is happening there on the device? Has somebody experienced something similar to this?

Thanks!

Comment: That second snippet of code has two open braces "{" and three close "}" , so I am not sure how it is all connecting.   Anyway here is a snippet of my code that works fine .  char *localityChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);   if (localityChars ==NULL) return FALSE;    , , as for the bind text , you are doing it different from my apps which do it : sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [myString UTF8String], -1,NULL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, following all your advices, and I think what solved the problem in the end was the case-sensitive thing. Thanks to u all

Comment: I'm glad to hear that I was right, am waiting an up-vote.. even :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be caused by empty records and your `if nil` doesn't help, try `NULL` instead:

```
if ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1) == NULL)
 userData.Name = @"";
```

Comment: weird, weird.. try to delete/reinstall your app in device, check again table name and the field names (on the device is case sensitive). Let us know.. the progress. Good luck!